# How can I sum of a list of list when the length is under 3 long for endless lists?

Tags: haskell

My code is working but not for endless lists. How can I make it work ?

```
sumsOf :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumsOf a = map sum [ x | x <- a , length x < 3]
```

Examples :

```
sumsOf [[],[1,2,4],[],[6]] == [0,0,6]
sumsOf [[1],[8],[6],[],[9,9]] == [1,8,6,0,18]
sumsOf [[1,2,9,10],[7,8,9],[6,9,4,2,0],[9,9,9]] == []
sumsOf [[1..],[7..],[6..],[9..],[10..],[100..]] == []
sumsOf [[1,2], [1..], [], [4]] == [3,0,4]
```

Comment: `a` is the big list-of-lists `[[a]]`, `x` is the small list `[a]`. So ...

Comment: Oh, thank you. How can I make it work for endless lists ?

Comment: Write a function that returns `True` if and only if its argument is a list of length of 2 or less. Do not use `length`. Take inspiration from [`null`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#null) and [`isSingleton`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.6.5/docs/src/Util.html#isSingleton).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easy-lazy solution:

You are only concerned about whether the length is less than 3, so the result is not changed if you truncate your input list at 3 elements:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> sumsOf a = map sum [ x | x <- a , length (take 3 x) < 3]
 λ> 
 λ> sumsOf [[],[1,2,4],[],[6]]
 [0,0,6]
 λ> sumsOf [[1],[8],[6],[],[9,9]]
 [1,8,6,0,18]
 λ> sumsOf [[1,2,9,10],[7,8,9],[6,9,4,2,0],[9,9,9]]
 []
 λ> sumsOf [[1..],[7..],[6..],[9..],[10..],[100..]]
 []
 λ> sumsOf [[1,2], [1..], [], [4]]
 [3,0,4]
 λ>
```

So this readily solves the problem with unlimited lists.

In slightly more idiomatic fashion:

```
sumsOf :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumsOf xss = map sum [ xs | xs <- xss , length (take 3 xs) < 3]
```

The sole drawback is that library function `take` has to duplicate the list nodes.

An idea mentioned in a comment by n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem: it is possible to have something a bit more efficient, by writing some `boundedLength` function that returns at most `k`, for example like this:

```
boundedLength :: Int -> [a] -> Int
boundedLength k xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go depth   []    =  depth
    go depth (x:xs)  =  if (depth < k)  then  go (depth + 1) xs
                                        else  k
```

In that case, our `sumsOf` function ends up as:

```
sumsOf :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumsOf xss = map sum [ xs | xs <- xss , boundedLength 3 xs < 3]
```

Comment: `boundedLength` can also be implemented efficiently (i.e. without duplicating list nodes), concisely, without explicit recursion, and sufficiently lazily with just things available in the `Prelude`, if you want a followup exercise.

Comment: @DanielWagner  Thanks for the suggestion. I have just tried to be more explicit.

Comment: Ah, if you're going to give the actual answer rather than leaving it as an exercise, then I'm happy saying what I was thinking explicitly, too: `atMostLength n = null . drop n`.

Answer (score 5):

`length` is one of the list functions that you should as a rule of thumb **never** use except when you know exactly why it's ok. (The other being `head` and `!!`.) It's not just because it doesn't work with infinite lists, but also because it does a usually completely unnecessary *O*(*n*) traversal over the entire list. Even if you need to traverse it anyway later, doing it twice can make a big performance difference.

In this case think about what you really need: a `sum` that avoids going into an long or infinite list but instead gives up after two elements. That could actually be implemented in a stupid exhaustion way:

```
sumIfLenLt3 :: Num a => [a] -> Maybe a
sumIfLenLt3 [] = Just 0
sumIfLenLt3 [x] = Just x
sumIfLenLt3 [x,y] = Just $ x+y
sumIfLenLt3 _ = Nothing
```

To make it general for any max-length, you could use recursion:

```
sumIfLenLe :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
sumIfLenLe _ [] = Just 0
sumIfLenLe 0 _ = Nothing
sumIfLenLe n (h:t) = h + sumIfLenLe (n-1) t
```

...but that's not such a good implementation, for two reasons: it blows up with negative arguments, and it isn't tail recursive. A better, albeit a bit cumbersome, version would be

```
sumIfLenLe :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
sumIfLenLe n l
  | n<0        = Nothing
  | otherwise  = go n l 0
 where go n [] acc  = Just acc
       go 0 _ _ = Nothing
       go n (h:t) acc = go (n-1) t (h+acc)
```

A bit more elegant is to use a standard function to take the max usable count of elements, and see if anything remains:

```
sumIfLenLe :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
sumIfLenLe n l
  | null remains  = Just $ sum relevant
  | otherwise     = Nothing
 where (relevant, remains) = splitAt n l
```

...or, some equivalent forms,

```
sumIfLenLe n l = case splitAt n l of
   (relevant, []) -> Just $ sum relevant
   _              -> Nothing
```

or

```
sumIfLenLe n l
 | (relevant, []) <- splitAt n l
              = Just $ sum relevant
 | otherwise  = Nothing
```

Then you can just map that over the entire given list and gather all the result that succeeded.

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

sumsOf :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumsOf = catMaybes . map (sumIfLe 2)
```